# How do I check with PHP if a file was attached to an HTML form?

Tags: php, html

I need to make sure that either the text was entered into the form's textarea input element or a file attached through the file input element.
I tried various things, including this:

```
if((empty($_POST['text'])) && (!empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']))) {
            $errors .= 'Please either enter your text or attach a file.<br/><br/>';
        }
```

Doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to display the error when both are empty or when both are not empty? But not if only one of both is filled? Strictly an OR thus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try

```
if((empty($_POST['text'])) || (empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']))) {
    errors .= 'Please either enter your text or attach a file.<br/><br/>';
}
```

You only want one OR the other so you ask if the "text" field is empty OR the "uploadFile" is empty

Comment: *Ahem*.. I think that you want that `||` to be an `&&` as it's only an error if *both* are empty :)

Comment: Be aware that the entry in the $_FILES array can be non-empty even when a file is not uploaded, you'll want to check that `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] === 0`.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't read it like at first. Perhaps he could look at it this way. What field does he want priority on, then even if both are filled, he takes the field that he wants, and leave the other, however, if only one is filled, he takes that one. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!
And sorry for having stolen your time.
I just made a typo - ! in front of empty - and didn't notice it.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_FILES!=null && $_POST!=null){
    $file = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];   

    if(!isset($file)){

       }
}
```

this is the code i have used

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((!empty($_POST['text']) && file_exists($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) || (empty($_POST['text']) && !file_exists($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))) {
    throw new Exception('must choose one or other');
}
```

this will pass if one is set or the other, but not both and not none.